# using arrows to show the next image

Tags: javascript

I came across this code for my project and have difficulty understanding parts of the code. I would like to know what does each line of code does. I tried to dissect each by line and have written what I think each line of code meant labeling it. Correct me if I got it wrong.

Each image has a width of 270px. From the screen, only 4 images can be seen (0-3). When the arrow is being utilized, the last image then will pop out (1-4). When the arrow is being clicked again, it will return to the original 4 images.

```
//declare arrow as constant
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
//.movie-list div containes all the movie images
const movieLists = document.querySelectorAll(".movie-list");

arrows.forEach((arrow, i) => {
  //an array is being created. Array called itemNumber have 4 items in it
  const itemNumber = movieLists[i].querySelectorAll("img").length;
  let clickCounter = 0;
  arrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const ratio = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 270);      // ratio = 4
    clickCounter++;
    if (itemNumber - (5 + clickCounter) + (5 - ratio) >= 0) {   //i don't get this part onwards
      movieLists[i].style.transform = `translateX(${
        movieLists[i].computedStyleMap().get("transform")[0].x.value - 300
      }px)`;
    } else {
      movieLists[i].style.transform = "translateX(0)";
      clickCounter = 0;
    }
  });

  console.log(Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 270));     // output=4
});
```

Comment: Documentation for 1) [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), 2) [computedStyleMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap).

Comment: I knew about the documentation. But it doesn't help me in uds the code above when i don't know  what the if programming part does

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188082) might help you rephrase your question in a way that will lead to more answers.

Answer (score 0):

I will do my best to give you a breakdown of what I see in the code line by line, in comparison to what you have described. If you had access to the html, or could create a working snippet demonstration of this in action, it would be easier to describe the action. However, there can still be mountains of information in the javascript alone!

```js
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
```

The left side has the keyword const. This keyword initializes a variable
the word immediately following is the name of the variable initialized,
in this case "arrows". From here on whenever the word arrows is used,
it will refer to the value generated to the right of the equal sign.

What makes the keyword `const` unique from `let` or `var`, for the most part
is that const variables can not be reassigned. However it is important
to remember mutable objects such as arrays can still be manipulated.

const is often chosen over var or let because it helps with common bug
issues by reducing human error!

The right side calls the variable name document which is standard in
browsers as a reference to the window's DOM. This variable has the
method `querySelectorAll` which returns all elements that match
the css selector passed as an argument. In this case, we have
the css selector `.arrow` which will select all elements with a
class of "arrow".

```js
const movieLists = document.querySelectorAll(".movie-list");
```

This is similar to the first line, movieLists will be all the
elements with the class "movie-list" from here on out.

```js
arrows.forEach((arrow, i) => {
```

This is calling the method `.forEach` on the iterable object `arrows`
We know arrows refers to all the items grabbed earlier
The `.forEach` method allows us to pass a function as an argument
and execute a block of code "for each" item in the arrows object

```js
  const itemNumber = movieLists[i].querySelectorAll("img").length;
```

The left of the equal sign is familiar to us, but on the right we
are using method chaining, or calling several methods or properties
on the same line. Lets break this down into 3 seperate statemenets

`movieLists[i]`

`movieLists` refers to the variable assigned earlier, and `i` refers
to the current index argument passed into this block of code. From
this block of code I would assume there are an equal number of arrows
as there are results for the movie lists, otherwise there would potentially
be an index that is out of bounds for movieLists, as `i` is referring to
the index given by the `forEach` method called on `arrows`
So for each item in `arrows` we are grabbing the same index from
`movieLists`. Lets add onto our statement so far.

`movieLists[i].querySelectorAll("img")`

We know `movieLists[i]` is the related item from the movieLists object
and the items stored in that object refer to elements in the DOM
we first grabbed those elements using `.querySelectorAll`, and just
like we used the method previously to select items from the root document
now we can use that method to select items that are specifically children
of `movieLists[i]`. Let us add onto our statement so far.

`movieLists[i].querySelectorAll("img").length`

We know `movieLists[i].querySelectorAll("img")` are all the items that
are children of `movieLists[i]` matching the css selector "img", which
are all the img tags. Once we have this iterable object, we can call
the property `.length` which will return the count of items that
matched our query.

```js
  let clickCounter = 0;
```

a major difference between `const` and `let` is that `let` can be
reassigned. This means the `clickCounter` variable initialized with
the value 0, will likely be changed at some point.

```js
  arrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
```

the arrow variable is referring to the argument passed into the
`.forEach` function called on `arrows`. Each `arrow` will have
and event listener added, listening for the event "click",
and when the event click is triggered, the anonymous arrow function
passed as an argument will execute.

```js
    const ratio = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 270);
```

a variable named ratio will be set to the value on the right.
On the right we have the `innerWidth` of the window, which is
a number of pixels, divided by the number 270. `Math.floor` is
converting the floating value with decimals into the closest
integer with less value.

```js
    clickCounter++;
```

this is shorthand for `clickCounter = clickCounter + 1;`

(increment clickCounter)

```js
    if (itemNumber - (5 + clickCounter) + (5 - ratio) >= 0) {
```

an if statement with `itemNumber - (5 + clickCounter) + (5 - ratio) >= 0`
as the conditional. If this expression resolves to the boolean true
the block of code will execute.
`itemNumber` refers to the number of img elements found
`clickCounter` refers to the number of times clicked
`ratio` refers to the math expression explained earlier

```js
      movieLists[i].style.transform = `translateX(${
        movieLists[i].computedStyleMap().get("transform")[0].x.value - 300
      }px)`;
```

This line uses a template literal which allows the use of ${} to
pass a js expression directly into the string.
We are grabbing the related movieLists item,
accessing the style property
accessing the transform property of the style
and setting it equal to a string. This string is
`translateX(?)` with the question mark being what the expression
resolved into.

The expression is
`movieLists[i].computedStyleMap().get("transform")[0].x.value - 300`
which takes the related movieLists element, calls a method `computedStyleMap()`
chaining the method `.get` to select the "transform" computed style
chaining the `.x` property and finally the `.value` property of x
to subtract 300 from that value, and place it into our template literal

```js
    } else {
      movieLists[i].style.transform = "translateX(0)";
      clickCounter = 0;
```

when our condition is not met, it looks like a reset is done
and transform is set to "translateX(0)" and clickCounter is reset to 0

```js
    }
  });

  console.log(Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 270));
});
```

At the end we have some logging for what appears to be debugging purposes.